# How do I change settings of a custom widget in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have this code where I want a button to trigger a change in a custom button. My solution only changes the color of all the custom buttons when they have been pressed. What would be the proper way to change the buttons?

python

```
class B_SettingScreen(Screen):
    def change_color(self):
        Factory.MainButton.background_normal = "z_MainButtonColorRed.jpg"
```

kivy

```
<MainButton@Button>:
    font_size: 18
    markup: True
    size_hint: 0.25,0.06
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_normal: "z_MainButtonColor.jpg"

<B_SettingScreen>:
    MainButton:
        text: "[b][font=Arial]Change Color[/b][/font]"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.25, "y":0.5}
        on_release: root.change_color()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (Thanks to @EL3PHANTEN in a different question I asked), just change it with the app class!

py

```
class Bobolo(App):
    bg_but = StringProperty("z_MainButtonColor.jpg")
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = 1,1,1,1
        return A_ScreenManager()
    def change_bg(self):
        self.bg_but = "z_MainButtonColorRed.jpg"
```

kv

```
<MainButton>:
    id: MainButton
    font_size: 18
    markup: True
    size_hint: 0.25,0.06
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_normal: app.bg_but


<B_SettingScreen>:

    MainButton:
        text: "[b][font=Arial]Change Color[/b][/font]"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.25, "y":0.5}
        on_release: app.change_bg()
```